# __extern_inline func results in undefined reference error

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

When I compile this c++ code with g++ 4.8.5 with -O0 -std=c++11,

```
#include <stdio.h>
__extern_inline float func(float x) { return x*x; }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   printf("%d\n", func(100));
}
```

I get this link error

```
/tmp/ccMiVRIL.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `func(float)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

however, if I add -O1 or -O2 to the compiler option, it builds successfully.
Also if I change "__extern_inline" to "extern __inline" or "__extern_always_inline", it also builds. I see similar behavior with clang.

I want to have that code (keep __extern_inline, since the definition lives in a third-party lib and I don't want to touch) to be able to link even under -O0. What can I do? Is there any compiler option or #defines to work this error around?

I've read this document, but it doesn't seem to help for my case
https://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline

Also it looks like __extern_inline is defined as follows in sys/cdefs.h

```
#define __extern_inline extern __inline __attribute__ ((__gnu_inline__))
```

Comment: Not the issue, but `"%d"` is wrong for a `printf` argument of type `float`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because following macro in `features.h`:

```
/* Decide whether we can define 'extern inline' functions in headers.  */
#if __GNUC_PREREQ (2, 7) && defined __OPTIMIZE__ \
    && !defined __OPTIMIZE_SIZE__ && !defined __NO_INLINE__ \
    && defined __extern_inline
# define __USE_EXTERN_INLINES   1
#endif
```

As you can see, extern inlines are explicitly allowed only for optimized builds.